# Has Anyone Got HTTP Compression Working with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, http, compression, gzip

I've spent quite a bit of time on this but seem to be going nowhere. I have a large page that I really want to speed up. The obvious place to start seems to be HTTP compression, but I just can't seem to get it to work for me.

After considerable searching, I've tried several variations of the code below. It kind of works, but after refreshing the browser, the results seem to fall apart. They were turning to garbage when the page used caching. If I turn off caching, then the page seems right but I lose my CSS formatting (stored in a separate file) and get an error that an included JS file contains invalid characters.

Most of the resources I've found on the Web were either very old or focused on accessing IIS directly. My page is running on a shared hosting account and I do not have direct access to IIS7, which it's running on.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Implement HTTP compression
    if (Request["HTTP_X_MICROSOFTAJAX"] == null) // Avoid compressing AJAX calls
    {
        // Retrieve accepted encodings
        string encodings = Request.Headers.Get("Accept-Encoding");
        if (encodings != null)
        {
            // Verify support for or gzip (deflate takes preference)
            encodings = encodings.ToLower();
            if (encodings.Contains("gzip") || encodings == "*")
            {
                Response.Filter = new GZipStream(Response.Filter,
                    CompressionMode.Compress);
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
                Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Accept-encoding"] = true;
            }
            else if (encodings.Contains("deflate"))
            {
                Response.Filter = new DeflateStream(Response.Filter,
                    CompressionMode.Compress);
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
                Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Accept-encoding"] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is anyone having better success with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had good results using `GZipStream` and `DeflateStream` to write the output directly, although I'm not familiar with the `Response.Filter` property. Give this a whirl:

```
string response = "your output body";
string accept = Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
if(accept == null) accept = "";
if (response.Length < 100 || !(accept.Contains("deflate") || accept.Contains("gzip")))
    Response.Write(response);
else
{
    byte[] compressed;
    bool useDeflate = accept.Contains("deflate");
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (Stream deflate = useDeflate
            ? (Stream)new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, true)
            : (Stream)new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(deflate))
            writer.Write(response);
        compressed = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Position = 0;
        stream.Read(compressed, 0, compressed.Length);
    }
    Response.Headers["Content-Encoding"] = useDeflate ? "deflate" : "gzip";
    Response.BinaryWrite(compressed);
}
```

Comment: Does this also go in Application_BeginRequest()?

Comment: Sadly I've only ever worked on the one ASP.Net project, and it's been this .ashx IHttpHandler thing, which lets you treat the entire response body as a string if you want to. I don't really know how it's done in regular .aspx pages. All the other C# I've worked on has been Win32 stuff. If ASP.Net has some sort of output buffering mechanism, this code would treat it just before it's flushed... wherever that may be. Sorry I can't be more specific!